# jQuery tabs not initializing after .load() in IE9 - works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zurb-foundation

### Quick Project Breakdown

My current project uses Java Spring MVC. In my presentation/view I am using `jsTree` with the ajax option to load in a generated xml file. `jsTree` then creates a tree menu of users. When you click on one of the menu items the userId is sent to a controllers and a user object is added to the map attributes. I then have to reload the contents a div so it uses this newly added map attribute. This loaded data is displayed inside jquery tabs.

I am using the [Foundation Framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/) for a mobile first design.

### Problem

This works fine in Chrome but when i try to run this in IE9 the data is being displayed in the div but the jQuery tabs do not initialize.

When i look in the IE developer toolbar console i get this:

```
HTML1114: Codepage iso-8859-1 from (HTTP header) overrides conflicting codepage utf-8 from (META tag) 
user-tool
SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited. 
user-tool
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'tabs' 
userTool.js, line 13 character 5
```

### Things i have tried

- Tried to verify my headers and meta tags were correct. I couldn't get it to format corrcetly, but wanted to make sure i didn't mess something up there [pastebin to the rescue](http://pastebin.com/FmWyAvuw)
- Tried using `jQuery.noConflict()` but that would only work after i clicked a few of the user menu items and it also broke some other stuff.
- I am currently looking to see if foundation is somehow getting in the way of the jquery libary.

### Possible Solution

It seems like there is a conflict with jquery and what zurb is doing. Everything starts to work nicely If i comment out the following script that foundation requires:

```
<script>

            document.write('<script src=' +
            ('__proto__' in {} ? '<c:url value="/js/vendor/zepto" />' : '<c:url value="/js/vendor/jquery" />') +
            '.js><\/script>')

        </script>
```

### Source Files

**userTool.js** - jquery source file that is linked at the bottom of the page [source](http://pastebin.com/cJDYHKzE)

**userForm.jsp** - jsp page that has the tabs. [source](http://pastebin.com/QtgvVht1)

### Edits

- Added Solution
- Removed wall of text source code and put them in pastebin's
- Added zurg-foundation framework tag and added mention of it.
- Updated status of what i am currently trying.